# Inequality of indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse

I was solving a problem and got stuck at step involving indicator function:

$$1_{y \in (\lambda-1,1)}>\gamma$$.

Is there any way in which I can write y in terms of $\lambda$?

I know that inverse of the $1_A$ can be written as:
$$1_A^{-1}(a,\infty)= A, \text{ if } a \in [0,1)$$

but I have no idea how to express y. Any hint or suggested reading will be helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $y \in (\lambda -1;\, 1)$ the max value of $1-\lambda = 1$ so max $\lambda=2$, with this, $y=\lambda - 1\Leftrightarrow \lambda=y+1$ with max $y=1$... so $1_{y\in(\lambda-1;\,1)}\equiv 1_{\lambda\in(y+1;\,2)}$

Comment: @Joako I am sorry, but perhaps I misunderstood your notation. Why is there ; ? $y$ lies in $(\lambda-1,1)$

Comment: In the indicator function of the question the domain where its value is $1$ is stated in your question as $1_{y\in(\lambda-1;\,1)}$... maybe I have misunderstood the notation but is what I interpreate reading that notation.

Comment: @Joako There is no ";" , there is ","

Comment: You are using the comma as a decimal part (like in spanish notation)?( $1,1 = 1+10^{-1}$)... or as the separation of two elements in an open set showing its boudaries? (like in $(a, \,\infty)$)

Comment: @Joako As in $(a,\infty)$

Comment: Then using $,$ or $;$ is irrelevant since both are lists separator characters, I change it to $;$ to emphasize it wasn't a decimal comma... but since it looks it doesn't help I will delete the comments in a few hours. Hope you find the answer you are looking for.